# Prove that the following running average is monotonically decreasing

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, sequences-and-series, exponential-sums

Let $S_n$ be defined as $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{t=n} [x^2+(p-q)x]$ where $x = 1-(1-p-q)^t$. We want to find the conditions on $p$ and $q$ such that $S_n$ is monotonically decreasing for all $n$. $0 < p,q < 1$ and $0 < 1-p-q < 1$.

Note:
Till now I have tried to get a closed bound expression for $S_n$ and differentiate it w.r.t. $n$ to get the conditions for a negative slope but it is getting really complex.

Another approach was to reduce this expression to the sum $S_n = C (>0) + \frac{1}{n}\left[q\sum_{t=1}^{n} \lambda^{2t} + (p-q) \sum_{t=1}^{n} \lambda^t \right]$ where $\lambda=1-p-q$. We know the upper bounds of the two sums, and since the denominator grows more rapidly than the numerator, it is sufficient to show that the numerator is positive to get a monotonically decreasing sequence.

Comment: $p\geq q$ is a sufficient condition.

Comment: If $p\leq q$, you can rewrite the questions with $a=p+q$, and $b=q-p$, and the condition $1\geq a\geq b\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S_n$ is always *increasing* in $n$. Note that $x$ is increasing in $t$; therefore, if $p\geq q$, then $x^2+(p-q)x$ is increasing in $t$.

If $q > p$, then you can set $a=1-p-q$, and $b=1-p+q$. The condition is $0<a\leq b<1$, and $x^2+(p-q)x=x(x-1+b)=(1-a^t)(b-a^t)$, which is increasing in $t$.

Comment: Hi Ron,

Thanks for the insights. I can't see how you have taken the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor into account. $x^2 + (p-q)x$ is increasing in $t$, therefore its summation is also increasing in $t$ but won't the $n$ factor in the denominator attenuate it?

Comment: when you have a (finite) set of numbers and you add to it another number which is greater than all the others, then the average increases.